# Can't move a UILabel position

Tags: uilabel, move, cgrect

I know, this is a stupid stupid question but after one day trying everything I've seen searching, I am uncapable of moving a UILabel, the code is this one:

```
CGRect frame = self.label_total.frame;
frame.origin.x = 500; // new x coordinate
frame.origin.y = 500; // new y coordinate
self.label_total.frame = frame;
```

it works if I put it in a IBAction, but I want to insert it in viewDidLoad, but It doesnt work. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this code little modified.
    must provide outlet to label.

```
CGRect frame1 = lbl_total.frame   ;
frame1.origin.x = 500; // new x coordinate
frame1.origin.y = 500; // new y coordinate
lbl_total.frame= frame1;
```